# Why can I chain setters with a class with builder class inside but cannot on a instance of a normal class?

Tags: java, builder

I've got introduced to builder pattern while learning java and I can't understand how builder can chain the setter methods.

```
//this one compiles
new AlertDialog.Builder().setApplyButton("apply").setText("stop");


//this one doesn't compile
new NormalAlert().setApplyButton("apply").setText("stop");
```

Comment: Because normal setters have return type of void. Builder ones return the builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Builder methods return `this` (the builder instance itself) so that more methods can be called on it. Generally, the method named `build` is defined to return the constructed object.

Example:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private Integer age;

  public static class Builder {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
        
    public Builder name(String name){
      this.name = name;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder age(Integer age){
      this.age = age;
      return this;
    }

    public Person build() {
        return new Person(this);
    }
  }

  private Person(Builder builder) {
    this.name = builder.name; 
    this.age = builder.age;     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in normal class setters usually return void you can't call another of your class setters on type void

Simple demonstration of builder pattern looks like this

```
public class Alert {
String prop1;
String prop2;
Alert(AlertBuilder builder){
    this.prop1 = builder.prop1;
    this.prop2 = builder.prop2;
}
}
class AlertBuilder{
String prop1;
String prop2;

public AlertBuilder setProp1(String prop1) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
    return this;
}
public AlertBuilder setProp2(String prop2) {
    this.prop2 = prop2;
    return this;
}
public Alert build(){
    return new Alert(this);
}
}
```

Where you have your main class and a builder class. Builder pattern keeps updating itself and when you are ready to build the "real" object you call build method and get all your fields at once.
I suggest you read more about Builder design patterns if you are interested.

Comment: I think this answer would be more complete if you explain what the `Builder` _does_ return, and why this allows the method chaining.

Comment: @Nexevis thanks for suggestion, I edited answer. Wanted to keep it simple what do you think?

Comment: @VojinPurić Thanks ! my bad, the return type flew over my head.